# Node.js: "Can't set headers after they are sent" error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code:

```
github.repos.getContent({
user: "user",
repo: "repo",
path: "path"
 }, function(err, res) {
var content = err;
console.log(err, res);
});

response.json({ message: 'Got content! ' + content});   

});
```

That github command outputs the content of a certain file, and I would like to manipulate the content. However, it either says "Can't set headers after they are sent" if I put it inside the function(err,res) part, or it says that var content hasn't been made yet if I do it outside. How do I get to use the output and manipulate it?

Comment: You've described 2 independent issues. 1) To have `content` within scope and accessible, you'll need to use it within the callback. It won't exist outside of that. 2) To resolve the "*Can't set headers after they are sent*" error, you'll need to make sure that this use of `response.json()` is the only response given for the current request. Check for any uses of `response.write()`, `response.send()`, `response.end()`, etc. elsewhere that may be altering the response before it.

Comment: Ah thanks. Now I got it to output content, but then content is only [object Object]. Do you know why?

Comment: When you convert an object to a string, in this case through concatenation, the default result is just `"[object Object]"`. To avoid that, you can use something to format it – e.g. `JSON.stringify()` – or avoid changing it to a string – e.g. as a separate key/value next to `message`.